# How to speed up JOIN and GROUP BY from huge table - 10 billions rows

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, database, nosql

I have a link table with two columns **usergroups(user int, group int)** containing ~10 billion rows. Every column have a 100 millions unique values. Indexes are created on both fields. I have to find groups with the most quantity of users who belong to specified group.

My query is

```
select group_id, count(*) as cnt
  from usergroups GM
       join (select user_id from usergroups where group_id=74437 LIMIT 100) G
       on (GM.user_id=G.user_id)
 group by group_id
 having cnt > 10
 order by cnt desc;
```

Without limitation of subquery it doesn't work (timeout error). Is it possible to speed up this query? Or maybe i should use some NoSql database for this issue?

Comment: What happens when you just join it without the subquery?

select GM.group_id, count(*) as cnt
  from usergroups GM
       join 
usergroups G
       on GM.user_id=G.user_id
 group by GM.group_id
 having cnt > 10
 order by cnt desc;

Comment: Maybe I'm not smart enough but I can't understand why you want to use a `JOIN` here. Why this `select group_id, count(*) as cnt from usergroups group by group_id` doesn't work?

Comment: It works but it's not what i need. I have to find similar groups with specified one. For example: group with id=74437 contains 1000 users, and this users are included to OTHER groups. I have to find these groups ordered by users count.

Comment: You complete lost me... I'm out!

Comment: Does usergroups have an index on user_id? I don't know MySQL but if you created an index for usergroups on (user_id, group_id) then in SQL Server at least it would be faster.

Comment: OP clearly stated:  "Indexes are created on both fields."

Comment: This query on Oracle 12c ~5 times faster then Mysql! But it not enough :(

Answer (score 0):

No need for inner/sub query.

For specific group_id, return data if it has more than 10 records, no need of group by clause has you are grouping for specific group_id, it returns only one record, if where and having clause are satisfied.

select group_id, count(*) as cnt
  from usergroups 
where group_id=74437
 group by group_id
 having cnt > 10

In general, get groups with their quantity greater than 10.

select group_id, count(*) as cnt
  from usergroups 
 group by group_id
 having cnt > 10
order by cnt desc

Comment: Subquery returns users who linked with many other groups. I have to  find groups with similar set of users. Maybe my explanation is not clear.. but query with inner/sub query represents the desired logic.